# Different sets of the same class variables within the same Monobehaviour class in c# (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, class, variables

I've been pondering about this for some time and I think I might just be missing an essential basic coding approach to resolve this, but I just can't think of it.
Basicly, in my script I'm trying to have different sets for the 'same variables' of the class where I can swap between (switching turrets ingame). If I would sketch the script, it would look something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Testturretscript : MonoBehaviour {

int ammo;
int maxAmmo;
float reloadTime;

set1(){
    ammo = set1.ammo;
    maxAmmo = set1.maxAmmo;
    reloadTime = set1.reloadTime;
}

set2()
{
    ammo = set2.ammo;
    maxAmmo = set2.maxAmmo;
    reloadTime = set2.reloadTime;
}



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    use set1;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad1) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1)){

        use set1;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad2) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2)){

        use set2;
    }
}

...

}
```

I know this might sound a bit cryptic, but there must be some easy way i'm missing to do this. Because when I swap back and forth, I do want to values to be properly stored instead of overriding the values of the variables.

Comment: Just create a `struct` to hold these values (and then have an array/`List`/whatever to pick from)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing this from memory, so bear with if there are some errors.

From your question, it looks like you are having multiple turret types, that a player can switch between at any time. A similar idea to a player carrying multiple guns that he can switch to at anytime.

So, you create a base class, in this case `Turret` which contains all the information common to a type of turret. All turrets will have an `ammo` count, `reloadTime` etc regardless of what type of turret it is.

Then, in the same script, we have our `Player` class. These two classes could be in different files, but for easier viewing, I've combined them into one.

The `Player` has an array of Turrets, or what turrets he can use. We create a `currentTurret` variable of the same type, so we can track which Turret the player is currently using.

First, we assign the `currentTurret` variable to the first Turret in our array (or inventory) of Turrets, using a custom index variable. We use this variable as it is easier to modify and look at rather than using numbers everywhere.

Then, in `Update`, if we press space, we increase the `currentTurretIndex` by one. We then set our current turret to the second turret in our array. This is basically switching weapons. WARNING! This is just for example, don't always just increase your index, as it will eventually get a null pointer exception. Instead, this should be a function that sets the current turret.

Then, if we press the `W` key, we tell our `currentTurret` to `Shoot()`. Because we have assigned our `currentTurret` variable to a turret in our array, only that turret will fire! Hooray!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Turret
{
    public int ammo;
    public int maxAmmo;
    public float reloadTime;

    public void Shoot()
    {
        // Do some shooting stuff!
    }
}

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Turret[] turretTypes;
    public Turret currentTurret;

    int currentTurretIndex = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        currentTurret = turretTypes[currentTurretIndex];
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            // Do your turret switching here.
            // For now I've just increased the turret index by 1.
            currentTurretIndex++;
            currentTurret = turretTypes[currentTurretIndex]
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            currentTurret.Shoot();
        }
    }        
}
```

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Yes and no. I understand the basic method behind your suggestion, however there is no player. You just control the turret that you can shoot with. When reading your code. Let's say I have two turrets. I should make a class for each turret with their variables (keeping them the same name) and then collect them into an array in a controller script, where I let all methods call upon the 'currentTurret' and it's variables?

Comment: I used `Player` as generic term. You could change `Player` to `TurretManager` instead, and assign different turrets to it. And no you should not make a new class script for each turret if they share the same variables, just reuse that script.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see what angle you are coming from. Quite clever! After some arguing with other code in my project I got it implemented and running! I'm just gonna use an integer to store the index value in, just to make sure i won't go outofbounds ;) Thank you very much, mate! I knew there had to be some way to do it, only couldn't figure the last 10%.